# Predefined values for .gitattributes

Tags: git

Sometimes people create **.gitattributes** file with list of known extensions and manually declare them as `text` or `binary`:

```
*.ts text
*.js text
*.json text
*.csv text
*.txt text
*.xml text
# etc.
```

Does Git have a default (built-in) list of popular file extensions (like .txt, .json etc.)? Does it make sense to manually declare well known extensions in each repo?

What happens if Git doesn't know extension?
Does it try to use heuristics by searching EOL symbols, or considers all unknown extensions as `binary`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does Git have a default (built-in) list of popular file extensions (like .txt, .json etc.)?

No.

> Does it make sense to manually declare well known extensions in each repo?

That depends on what you intend to put into your repository, and whether you must deal with Windows.

> What happens if Git doesn't know extension?

Git doesn't know extensions at all.

For users with ill-behaved systems (essentially, just Windows, these days), Git defaults to doing a quick scan of each file's content.  If the content appears binary, Git guesses that the file *is* binary and does not do any EOL conversions.  If the content appears to be text, Git guesses that it *is* text and does your selected EOL conversions.

On sane systems (basically everything *not*-Windows, these days), the default EOL conversion is "do not touch the data", so that even if Git detects the file as text, it does nothing to the data.  So here, there's never any need to do anything at all.

Comment: Doe it mean that if `core.autocrlf=true` (default on Windows) then Git scans contents of every single file in repo to heuristically determine is it text or binary?

Comment: @SergeyKostrukov: Not precisely, but close enough. Fortunately this is pretty trivial, as Git has to scan the contents of every file anyway. Doing a `git checkout` requires populating the index and work-tree from the commit being checked out. This consists of identifying which blobs go under which file names in the new commit, vs which ones went under which names in the old commit. Say, for instance, that the current commit has three files A, B, and C; the new commit has three files named C, D, and E. [continued]

Comment: To switch from current to new, Git must: remove A, remove B, decide whether file C is to be replaced, extract and write out D, and extract and write out E. If C has the *same* hash in old and new commits, Git can leave it alone and just worry about D and E. If it has a *different* hash, Git must extract C, D, and E. So Git is either reading two files, or three files. [cont'd]

Comment: At this point, Git knows it must copy the files into the index and work-tree. The copy into the index is trivial: write index entries with the correct hash ID and work-tree `stat` data. Copying into the *work-tree*, however, means *decompress the compressed objects*. During the decompression, Git gathers file content statistics: does this file look binary, or does it look text-y? Now that the file is decompressed, Git writes it to the work-tree, doing any EOL filtering. The slow part is the decompression and writing, not the detecting and EOL conversion.

Comment: Similar rules hold during `git add`: Git scans the work-tree and/or the indicated paths, uses `lstat` to compare them to the index contents, and decides whether the index copies must be updated. If so, Git must read the files and compress them and write the compressed objects into the repo. In the process of reading, Git gathers the content statistics. The slow part is reading the files, compressing, and writing the objects, not the analysis and EOL conversion.